# Execute the batch file from UNC path

Tags: batch-file, network-shares

I am running the batch file on my local machine which calls the exe on network share. Will it consume the memory of my local machine and does the exe gets copied on my local machine before starting it.

### test.bat

```
\\server1\gc.exe "param1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.exe` file will be read from the network share into local memory
and executed on your computer. This goes also for the `.bat` file,
if it also resides on the share.

It will execute in the current folder as when the batch file was started,
so for a different folder you should add a `cd` command.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the bat file is also on the network share. So both bat file and exe will be copied on our local machine and executed?

Comment: @Sundeep they are not copied to the harddisk of the local machine. They are read directly into memory.

Comment: Yes, they will. For a very long `.bat` file, it will be read into memory in chunks as executed. The `.exe` needs to be totally read into memory in order to execute.